# ASP.NET MVC3 passing data between primary view and a search view via Ajax link

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have just started learning ASP.NET MVC3.

I have the following scenario. In a create view for a certain model the user can lookup code/description by clicking on a link (rendered with Html.ActionLink helpers).  The lookup values are retrieved from lookup tables in a database and presented in a separate view. The two views are handled by two different controllers.  When the user selects a lookup value in the latter view that value (code+description) should be copied back to the create view.

How can data be passed between the two views? Is this not possible due to the stateless nature of Http requests?

I tried that with an Ajax link, but it didn't worked out.

code snippet Create view:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend>Z-Info</legend>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ZZL_U_CODE)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ZZL_U_CODE)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ZZL_U_CODE)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Ajax.ActionLink("Land code test", "Index", "Domein", new {name = "lan" }, 
            new AjaxOptions {
                HttpMethod = "Get",
                Url = Url.Action("Index", "Domein", new {name = "lan" }), 
                OnBegin = "OnBegin",
                OnSuccess = "InsertCodeNaam",
                OnFailure = "OnFailure",
                OnComplete = "OnComplete"
            })
    </div>
```

When the user select a code/description the following `Select` action is called which returns `Json` data back.

Select action:

```
public class DomeinController : Controller
{
    private ZZLEntities db = new ZZLEntities();

    //
    // GET: /Domein/

    public ViewResult Index(string name)
    {
        DomeinViewModel model = DomeinRepositry.GetAll(name);
        return View(model);
    }



     GET: /Domein/Select/5

    public JsonResult Select(int id, string naam)
    {
        return Json(new DomCodeNaam { codeValue = id, naamValue = naam }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Are there other solutions possible? Can partial views be an option?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have two options:

1. Just post back lookup values and then internally redirect to the
   first ("create") view, but this time passing (internally) the values
   chosen by user so the view can be rendered with chosen values. Maybe
   not fancy but very easy to implement. You will loose data that user have already entered into first form though, unless you post it too or you make this a 2 step process.
2. If you want to use Ajax, you need update appropriate parts of the
   form in the first "create" view on the client side, depending on the
   actions of user (i.e. what lookup values they have chosen).

I am however a bit confused with what you exactly mean by "separate view"

Comment: Hi Mariusz, thanks for answering.  I want to clarify what i meant with "separate" view. See it as different web pages. Of course MVC doesn't deal with web pages. Your suggestion to 'post back' the lookup values to create view.  How can i achieve that, knowing that ASP.NET MVC doesn't support a postback mechanism?  Maybe i can put the lookup data in TempData (a sort of session data with a short life span) and do RedirecToAction to the create action in the controller of the create view. Problem is how can i maintain the "viewstate" between switching of views.

Comment: @sliem With the 1. I was thinking about moving a user from one view to another, that is: create view with link to lookup action -> lookup view with form that redirects to create action -> create view (with selected value) -> final form submission. So only one page is shown to user at any time. The lookup value can passed between actions internally with optional parameter ActionResult Create(other parameters, Lookup values = null) or you can set you view model accordingly before redirection Model.LookupValue = "blah blah" and then redirect to Create(model).
You can always use Session object.

Comment: @Or 2. may be better option if you ok with JS/jQuery. Use e.g. BlockUI [link](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos) to display the lookup form and once the user chooses value modify create form with the values.

Comment: Ok. Instead of AjaxList, render action (which need to return partial view now). @Html.RenderAction("Index","Domain", new { name = "lan" }). This will render html where you look up values. In that partial view you need to generate some elements (links?) with id and naam. Then you need to add jScript to replace the content of #ZZL_U_CODE with the "hidden" value when someone clicks the element. Eg. create  link with name="id/code". Bind click event with code that will get id and code from name="id/code" and put it into #ZZL_U_CODE.

Comment: Instead of links you could also use dropdown list and bind to the onchange event (which fires when a user choose new value from drop down list. Option elements have attribute "value" which are ideal for your id and they also have text which should show your "naam" values. In the script you need to copy necessary information from selected option to #ZZL_U_CODE. And that's it.